# ANDing unsigned binary representations

Tags: c#, binary, bit-manipulation, cpu-architecture

I am trying to AND two difference binary number.
so far that is my code (i posted to pastebin as im not sure i got the layout right on here)
http://pastebin.com/FRT6Qig6

My problem is I just dont understand what my answer should be. Or even if my code is doing the right thing.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Two {
        public void run() {
            byte a = 255;
            byte b = 85;
            byte c;

            a = Convert.ToByte("10101111", 2);  //85
            b = Convert.ToByte("011111111", 2); //255

            c = (byte) (a & b);

            Console.WriteLine
                ("ANDing two bytes  - decimal:{0:D3}  hex:{0:x2}  binary:{1}",
                 c, Convert.ToString(c, 2));

            //wait until next press
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't help you until you ask a question.

Comment: What should my answer be? When I AND 255 and 85. Also is that what my code should be doing?

Comment: Do note that 85 should be `1010101`, not `10101111`.

Comment: @Alex - You need to do some research so you are able to determine the correct answer.  You can't expect us help understanding how AND'ing two base 2 numbers.  Do you know conditions where X AND Y are True?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=255+%26+85

Answer (score 2):

Because all the bits in a byte are turned on for the unsigned representation of `255` in binary, ANDing *any* single-byte value with `255` will return your input *unchanged*:

```
0x1 & 0xFF == 0x1
0x2 & 0xFF == 0x2
..
0xFE & 0xFF == 0xFE
0xFF & 0xFF == 0xFF
```

AND only gets more interesting when one of the values doesn't have every bit turned on:

```
0101 0101 & 0000 1111 == 0000 0101
```

Answer (score 0):

> What should my answer be?

I will go ahead and answer this question

The truth table for A AND B is the following:

A  B   Value
1  1   1
1  0   0
0  1   0
0  0   0

The truth table for A OR B is the following:

A  B   Value
1  1   1
1  0   1
0  1   1
0  0   0